# Laravel Problem: Please check why this code behave like this?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$sallery_min = 4000;
$sallery_max = 30000;

$job = Job::where('status', 1);
      
if ($sallery_min && $sallery_max) {
    $job->whereIn('salary_level', $sallery_level);
}
      
$data = $job->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
dd($data);
```

when use above mention code then i got 7 result its working fine. But when i change in this code like this then 11 result come from database.can i do not do code like this. what happen when Job::where('status', 1); change into `$job = new Job(); $job->where('status', 1);`. why result come diffrent

```
$sallery_min = 4000;
$sallery_max = 30000;

$job = new Job();
$job->where('status', 1);
      
if ($sallery_min && $sallery_max) {
    $job->whereIn('salary_level', $sallery_level);
}
         
$data=$job->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
dd($data);
```

Comment: Presumably the static version of the "where" function and the instance version of that function do different things. Hard to know without seeing the Job class.

Comment: This is Job Model class in Laravel there is no code regarding this. its functionality inbuild by laravel. i want to just know why this happen even we doing same code

Answer (score 1):

in your code you are getting the result where status is 1 1 from your database by using this query

```
$job = Job::where('status', 1);
```

but you are not retriving the objects because you dont use **get()** or **first()**.WHer `first()` is use for retrieving single row and `get()` is use for multipe row. So for retrieving teh expected result you have to use `get()` method like this.

```
$jobs = Job::where('status', 1)->get();
```

Comment: i think you not understand my question. i put 2 code. 1st code is working fine like a filter but see in 2nd code i use new Job() but with this approch i am getting 11 row from database while in 1st i am getting 7 row. both code is same then why result is diffrent

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the database with a new `Job` object, you should use the method chaining, like:

```
$job = new Job();

$jobs = $job->where('status', 1)
        ->when($sallery_min && $sallery_max, function ($q) use ($sallery_min, $sallery_max) { 
            return $q->whereBetween('salary_level', [$sallery_min, $sallery_max]);
        })->get();

dd($jobs);
```

> However, Eloquent provides the `static` method for convenience. Use it unless you have a specific reason to stick on with the new Object word around.

> Extra Note:
> The above code uses [Conditional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#conditional-clauses) which avoids `if ... else ...` statements.

Comment: no i just want to know what happen in code why this working diffrently when using as new job(). even i am working same work as above code. so why its not getting same result like above code

Comment: @CoreCoding It is simple. `$job = new Job()` creates a new `Job` Model. If not chained,  it executes the last order by statement only (Not the where and wherein statements). Upvote/Approve the answer if you got what you're looking for.

Comment: you are right @Ash1271 its exicuting last statement only not where or whereIn. so my point is why this happen when use new Job() ?

Comment: First one is `Eloquent\Builder `  method, which will add a `where clause` to the query and return the `$query`. The second one `is a Model instance` (= a row in your database). You can call the `Builder` methods using a Model object, but it is not returning the `query` , and remains the same model instance.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is clear. 

The same behavior (method chaining) can be obtained with this code as well. 
```
$job = new Job();

  $job = $job->where('status', 1);

  $jobs = $job->get();
```

I hope this will help you understand better.